# Как открыть окно "Средства диагностики" в Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Искомое окно выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Скрин - как должен выглядеть interface]

Как получить к нему доступ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данное окно доступно в пункте меню Debug

<kbd>Debug</kbd>→<kbd>Windows</kbd>→<kbd>Show Diagnostic Tools</kbd>

Либо по горячим клавишам: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение могу сказать, что начиная, кажется, с 2013 Студии появилось универсальное окно поиска, расположенное справа вверху. Стоит в него ввести, например, "diag", как вывалится список со всеми окнами и опциями, которые имеют в названии "diag". Очень удобная вещь, когда не знаешь/не помнишь, где находится нужное окно или настройка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: круто! не замечал это окно, оно во всех версиях есть?

Comment: @Grundy "начиная, кажется, с 2013 Студии" :). Во всех редакциях. Хотя возможно и в 2012 уже было.

Comment: да, я имел ввиду редакции